# Exclude Fields From Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Let's say I have a following `ViewModel` :

```
    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is a `ViewModel` not a original `Entity`, I use this model in two places, in the first one I want to validate all fields, but in another one I want to exclude `Email` field from model validation. Is there anyway to specify to exclude field(s) from validation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
ModelState.Remove("Email");
```

to remove entries in model state, that are related to hidden fields.

The best solution is to divide view model into two:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonWithEmailViewModel : PersonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but what about using `[Bind(Exclude = "IsAdmin")]` ?

Comment: @EAmani: Bind exludes from binding, not validation. If you don't want to have these problems, create dedicated view model.

Comment: Great answer, I separated one class into two and made one a super class of the other, made my validation easier

Answer (score 8):

An ugly solution:

```
ModelState.Remove("Email");
```

Recommended solution:
Create another ViewModel. A VM is supposed to represent your view, so if your view has no Email field, make a suitable VM for it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes you are right, its better to create another VM for my second view.